# Atom editor snippets in json with multi line body

Tags: atom-editor

How i can add Atom snipp in JSON with many lines, it works as below in Vscode

```
"snip name": {
  "prefix": "t",
  "body": [
    "line1",
    "line2",
    "line3"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost the same in Atom, with two minor differences:

1. The scope for a snippet is declared in the snippets file, while for Visual Studio Code it's declared in the manifest (`package.json`)
2. The body is a single string with line-breaks

**Example:**

The following snippet basically does the same as your's and works in plain-text files only.

```
{
  ".text.plain": {
    "snip name": {
      "prefix": "t"
      "body": "line1\nline2\nline3",
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can save your snippet as [CSON](https://github.com/bevry/cson) and use multiline strings

**Example:**

```
".text.plain":
  "snip name":
    prefix: "t"
    body: """
    line1
    line2
    line3
    """
```

Comment: If the answer helped you, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark left of it https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer